# Entity Framework: Avoiding primary key violation in child object

Tags: entity-framework

I'm quite new to EF so this may be quite simple.

Basically I want to add multiple child objects with the same primary key but I keep getting a primary key violation.

I'm wondering how to add a list of objects that contain child objects with the same primary key without throwing an exception. I am hoping there is a way to tell the Add() to ignore the child insert if it exists.

I've created 2 simple classes to describe this better.

```
Public class Race
{
    Int Id;
    EventType Event;
}

Public class EventType
{
    Int Id;
    String Description;
}

Var event1 = new EventType();
event1.id = 1

Var event2 = new EventType();
event2.id = 1

Race race1 = new Race();
race1.id = 99;
race1.EventType = event1;

Race race2 = new Race();
race2.id = 100
race2.EventType = event2;
```

Now in my DbContext I just want to do:

```
Db.Add(race1);
Db.Add(race2);
SaveChanges();
```

This throws a primary key violation.

It works okay if I assign the same EventType object to both Race instances but I can't do this in reality as this parent object has been created externally by a data feed.

Answer (score 0):

```
Var event1 = new EventType();
event1.id = 1

Var event2 = new EventType();
event2.id = 1
```

Above code snippet says that you want to add two rows in events table with same primary key value as 1 which is not possible in database because primary keys are always with unique constraints.

> > how to add a list of objects that contain child objects with the same primary key without?

Above sentence is not much clear but if it targets same event to be attached to multiple Races then it can be done like following.

```
Var event1 = new EventType();
event1.id = 1

Race race1 = new Race();
race1.id = 99;
race1.EventType = event1;

Race race2 = new Race();
race2.id = 100
race2.EventType = event1;
```

and then calling `context.SaveChanges()`.

Comment: Janish, thanks for your answer but as stated I cannot do your suggestion as the data comes to me as different objects. I am wondering what the best ways are to achieve inserting the multiple parent objects with child objects that have the same id.

Comment: @Atomic800 It is not possible at all to have two objects/row in db with same primary key unless it is combined primary key. If you want same primary key just to track relationship between `race` and `eventtype` object then above solution should work.

Comment: I understand the concept of a database primary key. The question I'm asking is how best to achieve not trying to insert the duplicate child object using Entity Framework?